# Boltzmann vs Gibbs definition of entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am learning Statistical Mechanics and I have a question regarding different definitions of
(statistical) entropy. If we use Boltzmann's definition:

$$\sigma \propto\ln(W)$$

Where $\sigma$ is the entropy of the macrostate associated with the microstates $W$. However, this means that entropy is a property of macrostates, not of microstates. If a macrostate corresponds to a single microstate, then the entropy is zero.

We can instead define the entropy per microstate as:

$$\sigma_i=-\ln(P_i)$$

Where $\sigma_i$ is the entropy of the "i"-th microstate, and $P_i$ is the probability of observing said microstate. Using this definition of entropy for microstates, we can then define the entropy of a macrostate as:

$$\sigma=\langle\sigma_i\rangle$$

Where $\langle\sigma_i\rangle$ is the average entropy over all the microstates of the respective macrostate. Is the latter (Gibbs entropy) simply a more general version of Boltzmann's definition, and hence better? Is it okay to define entropy for a given microstate or does give problems down the line?

Comment: Apart from the problem of the duplicate, you should take into account that there is nothing like an entropy per microstate defined as $-\log P_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the average of a quantity is defined by
$$
\langle A\rangle = \sum_i P_i A_i,
$$
the entropy by definition can be viewed as the average of the negative logarithm of the probability of a microstate
$$
\sigma = -\sum_iP_i\log P_i = \langle -\log P\rangle.
$$
This is just a mathematical fact (which may occasionally turn out to be convenient).

Note however, that here we are dealing with *information/Shannon* entropy, of which *Boltzmann entropy* is a particular case (mathematically), when all the state have the same probability ($P_i=1/W$, [see also this post and reference therein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709644/how-to-derive-shannon-entropy-from-clausius-theorem/709656#709656)). Boltzmann entropy has however many special properties related to the nature of the microstates in thermodynamic systems, so one should really distinguish the two.

*Gibbs entropy* is defined *phenomenologically* via clausius inequality, but can be shown to be equivalent to *microscopically* defined Boltzmann entropy.