# What is the difference between Clausius' entropy and Boltzmann's?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, definition

We can only speak of entropy change, $dS$, when I mention Clausius as
$$dS=δQ/T$$

However, according to Boltzmann, entropy is defined as $S=K\ln\Omega$

My question is, is the $S$ according to Boltzmann an entropy change as well? Or is it the entropy of the state whose disorder number is $\Omega$ and accordingly, $ds=k\ln(\Omega_2/\Omega_1)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive Shannon Entropy from Clausius Theorem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709644/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, is the  according to Boltzmann an entropy change as well?

No -- Boltzmann gives a value to the entropy, not just the change in entropy.

Even in pure thermodynamics, (i.e., using Clausius's definition), the *third law of thermodynamics* also fixes the absolute value of the entropy. The third law says that the entropy must approach a constant at zero temperature, where the constant is given by Boltzmann's constant times the natural log of the number of degenerate ground states of the system.